# Find $a_7h_{24}+a_{14}h_{17}$, if $a_1,a_2,...$ are in A.P and $h_1,h_2,...$ are in H.P

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> Let $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots \cdots $  are in A.P. and $h_1,h_2,\cdots \cdots\cdots  $ are in H.P.
> If $a_1=h_1=2$ and $a_{30}=h_{30}=25$,
> then $a_7h_{24}+a_{14}h_{17}$ equals

What I try : From A.P :

$\displaystyle a_{30}=a_{1}+(30-1)d$

$\displaystyle 25=2+29d\Longrightarrow d=\frac{23}{29}$

So we have $\displaystyle a_{7}=a_1+6d=2+6(\frac{23}{29})$

and we have $\displaystyle a_{14}=a_1+13d=2+13(\frac{23}{29})$

We have $h_1,h_2,h_3,\cdots \cdots ,$ are in  H.P

Then $\displaystyle \frac{1}{h_1},\frac{1}{h_2},\cdots \cdots $ are in A.P

So we have $\displaystyle \frac{1}{h_{30}}=\frac{1}{h_{1}}+29d\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{25}=\frac{1}{2}+(29)d$

So we get $\displaystyle d=-\frac{23}{50\times 29}$

So $\displaystyle \frac{1}{h_{24}}=\frac{1}{a_1}+(23)d=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{23^2}{50\times 29}$

And we have $\displaystyle \frac{1}{h_{17}}=\frac{1}{a_1}+16d=\frac{1}{2}-16(\frac{23}{50\times 29})$

Can I solve above question using some less lengthy way i.e by using properties of A.P and H.P

Because I observe that in $a_7a_{24}$ and in $a_{14}a_{17}$ suffix sum is same i.e $31$.

Please have a look, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start from
$$a_n = a_1 + (n-1)d_{AP} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{1}{h_n}=\frac{1}{h_1} + (n-1)d_{HP}$$
$$\frac{a_n - a_1}{\frac{1}{h_n} - \frac{1}{h_1}} = \frac{d_{AP}}{d_{HP}} \color{blue}{ = \frac{a_{30} - a_1}{\frac{1}{h_{30}} - \frac{1}{h_1}}}=-50$$
The colored step signifies that we do not need to even calculate $d_{AP}, d_{HP},$ since their ratio is constant for all $n$. Rearranging
$$\frac{a_n - a_1}{\frac{1}{h_n} - \frac{1}{h_1}} = -50 \Rightarrow a_n + \frac{50}{h_n} = a_1 + \frac{50}{h_1} = 27 $$
By property of arithmetic progressions, $a_n + a_{31-n}=a_1+a_{30}=27$. Therefore
$$a_n + \frac{50}{h_n} = a_n + a_{31-n} \quad \Rightarrow \quad a_{31-n}h_n = 50$$
This is sufficient [although we can replace $n$ by $(31-n)$] to state that $a_nh_{31-n} = 50$ is a constant!